# How can I source the bashrc file command correctly?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on transferring a pipeline to another server and I am having issues with the source `$HOME/.bashrc` command.
The pipeline is a series of bash scripts that is being initialized by a cronjob. At the beginning of a few scripts it has `source $HOME/.bashrc`. When I run the script that is starting after the one on the cronjob on the terminal everything works fine.

However, when the pipeline starts with the cronjob I am having issues. The first 2 scripts work but the 3rd one does not. That scripts sets the path using `source $HOME/.bashrc` but it seems that it is not set correctly. The script needs the path from 2 packages that are both specified on the bashrc file. However, it finds only one of them. I checked that by adding on my script

```
fastqc_version=$(fastqc --version)
echo "FastQC version: $fastqc_version"
parallel_version=$(parallel --version)
echo "Parallel version: $parallel_version"
```

The parallel version comes up empty.

Then I added `echo "Updated PATH: $PATH` after the source command and I see that the path is not set correctly which explain why it does not find the path to parallel but I don't understand how it finds the path to fastqc.

Then I did `echo "$HOME/.bashrc"` to find the location of my bashrc file so then I set it up `source /home/ab/.bashrc` in my script. However, it still sets the same path as before and I am having the same issue with parallel. What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you

Comment: The source command does *not* update your path. It only executes commands inside `.bashrc`. You need to add something like `export PATH=/some/thing:$PATH` into your `.bashrc` then source it.

Comment: My .bashrc has both of these included: 
 `export PATH=/data/Resources/Software/FastQC:$PATH
export PATH=/data/Resources/Software/parallel/bin:$PATH`
If I write  `source $HOME/.bashrc ` on the terminal and I check the versions of the packages that I have specified their path on the  .bashrc they all seem to be specified correctly.

Comment: _Which_ crontab did you create that cronjob in? Meaning _which_ user account? Maybe the `$HOME` variable simply isn't set in that case?

Comment: Additionally, the cron-user doesn't have a `$HOME` to run from, so if that is the user executing the pipeline, calls to `"$HOME/.bashrc"` will not find the file.

Comment: I created it from my account. I added the below in my script. The output of the first echo is the path that I am using to source.
`source /home/a/.bashrc
echo "$HOME/.bashrc"
echo "Updated PATH: $PATH"`

Should I just specify the paths at the beginning of my script then since I cannot get the bashrc file to work?

Comment: You did not specify what you mean by _pipeline_. However I would reconsider the design: `.bashrc` is intended for **interactive** shells, and therefore does not make much sense in a scripted environment. For better maintenance, I would put the PATH settings into a separate file, which you then source in your script. If they should apply  also to interactive shells, source this file from within your .bashrc as well.

Comment: To further investigate, it would be helpful if you showed the crontab entry and the relevant content of the sourced file, and the relevant parts of the failed script.